# Trick monitor into receiving signal

Tags: led-driver, vga, monitor, backlight

I have the plan to convert a few old LED backlit monitors into false windows. While I theoretically *could* buy direct LED drivers to power these panels, I'd prefer to keep the existing circuitry, since I know it works and provides the right voltage and current ratings.

The problem is that by nature, without an actual input, these monitors automatically turn off after just a couple minutes.

The question is - how can I trick a monitor (via VGA or DVI) to think they're attached to something and not automatically shut off after idle time?

PS - The LCD panels have already been removed. It's just the backlight.

Comment: https://tehnikservice.net/2010/04/25/attiny2313-monitor-tester/

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20070707045927/http://eosystems.ro/deogen/download/

Comment: Since the panels are gone probably you can't open the OSD menu. Anyway, all monitors I know have a preference for shut off when idle that can be switched off.

Comment: The proposed duplicate I already saw, and is not what I am looking for. As mentioned, I have removed the LCD panel and only need the backlight. I don't need to give it any color whatsoever. Just make it think it has a signal.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need acceptable signals on the HSYNC and VSYNC pins of the VGA connector.

most monoitors complain and then shut down the the sync frequency is out of range, but with the LCD removed you won't be able to see that message.

it might be easier to trace the circuit that controls the backlight and bypass the shutdown mode.

Comment: All the monitors I have opened have have been easy enough to figure out.  The control is typically a digital signal for enable and a 0-5V analogue signal brightness. I have variously replaces the control by jumper wires or pots many times.

Answer (score -1):

Try connecting all the ground pins of the VGA connector of your LED Monitor. Maybe that will trick your Monitor that something is connected to the VGA Port.

[image]
Source: http://land-boards.com/blwiki/index.php?title=File:Vga_pinout.JPG